# Custom listener not working in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to implement an Interface as a Listener which gets fired from a service. The listener setter works fine but when I try to use callback `onStatusChanged()` it doesn't work. Please let me know if we can use Listeners in services or not.

CustomService.kt

```
class CustomService : Service(){

    object Status{
         var serviceRunning:Boolean = false
    }

    interface StatusListener{
        fun onStatusChanged(status:Boolean) = Unit
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        val returnVal = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
        Status.serviceRunning = true
        val testRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,             
            "api.chandanmahto.com",
            Response.Listener {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Service has been started! You can now close the app",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show() // this toast is shown
                statusListener?.onStatusChanged(true)
            },
            Response.ErrorListener {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Server cannot be reached!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
                statusListener?.onStatusChanged(false)
                stopSelf()
            }
        )
        queue.add(testRequest)
        return returnVal
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    fun setStatusListener(listener: StatusListener){
        // this runs without problem
        statusListener = listener
    }
}
```

DashboardActivity.kt

```
class DashboardActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var serviceLog: TextView
    private lateinit var service: Intent
    private val adrsService: ADRSService = ADRSService()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard)
        serviceLog = findViewById(R.id.service_logs)
        service = Intent(this, ADRSService::class.java)
        serviceSwitch.setOnClickListener {
            serviceLog.text = getString(R.string.dashboard_service_working)
            if (serviceSwitch.isChecked) {
                startService(service)
            } else {
                stopService(service)
                serviceLog.text = getString(R.string.dashboard_service_stopped)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
        adrsService.setStatusListener(object : ADRSService.StatusListener {
            override fun onStatusChanged(status: Boolean) {
                Log.d("LISTENER", "Listener Fired")    // this doesn't get logged.
                serviceLog.text =
                    if (status) getString(R.string.dashboard_service_started) else getString(R.string.dashboard_service_stopped)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

P.S I am new to Kotlin, so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Services don't work as you expect, you can't create an instance of `Service` and set listener there, you should use `Intent` to start it and, for example, `BroadcastReceiver` to no notify Activities about changes. Services overview https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Comment: Thank you. I was starting to learn ```Services``` and tried to use Listeners to visually debug it. I will look into ```BroadcastReceiver```

Comment: You can also Bind a service to an Activity and receive updates that way